# My browser Chrome couldn't access any website with only home wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, browser

Few day ago, my chrome start fail to access any website with error ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED and ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

With my home wifi, I test very common like www.youtube.com and www.google.com on all browser in my laptop. And I found out only Google Chrome and IE unable to access while Firefox and Comodo Dragon able to access those websites.

Then I connect my laptop to another wifi (my phone hotspot wifi), chrome, IE and Firefox is work as normal. But now Comodo Dragon browser fail to access.

I tried reinstall google chrome but issue still exists.

How can it possbile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, Internet Explorer and Google Chrome respect the LAN and proxy settings on your computer, while Firefox has its own setting. So, check the proxy settings on your computer to check if they are right. You can access the system proxy settings from Google chrome settings System -> Open Proxy settings.